# Question about xsd. Elements inside complex type must be allowed in any order

Tags: xsd

If you look at the following xsd fragment you can conclude that the corresponding xml will first contain cars followed by busses eg:

```
car,car,bus,bus
```

HOWEVER I want the xml to be able to contain

```
car,bus,car,bus
```

What change do I need to make in the xsd below in order to achieve this?

```
<xs:element name="body">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="session" type="tns:session" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="car" type="tns:car" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="bus" type="tns:bus" />
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit cumbersome, but you might achieve what you're looking for like this:

- create a `<xs:choice>` element with your car and bus elements inside; this defines that one of the contained elements can be used
- make sure to have the attribtues `minOccurs=1` and `maxOccurs=unbounded` on that `<xs:choice>` - this gives you any number of either car or bus elements - any number, any combination

So your XML schema would look something like this (I added some stuff just to be able to generate a sample XML and verify it works - tweak as needed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="body">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="car" type="CarType" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="bus" type="BusType" />
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="CarType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Maker" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="BusType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Maker" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Capacity" type="xs:int" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Using `<xs:choice>` is the way to go. However, there is no need for the additional sequence element. A `<choice>` element can also have `minOccurs` and `maxOcurrs` defined sothat the list length can be unbounded.

Comment: @pmartin: ah, excellent - thanks, that makes things even easier! I'll update my answer accordingly...

Answer (score -1):

use `<xs:any>` insted of `<xs:sequence>`

Comment: when i change it to xs:any i get the message "element is not supported in this context"

Comment: If i change it to xs:all then i can no longer use the maxOccurs="unbounded". Meaning that the xml can only contain one element of each :(.  Any suggestions ?